# Don't understand why swift wants me to be explicit

Tags: swift

I am testing out swift and don't understand why the following lines don't work.

```
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [MyViewController1(), MyTableViewController2()]

    tabBarController.tabBar.items[0].title = "First"
    tabBarController.tabBar.items[1].title = "Second"
```

The compiler tells me: `Could not find member 'title'`

If I split the arguments apart into multiple variables, then it works.

```
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.viewControllers = [MyViewController1(), MyTableViewController2()]

    let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar 
    let tabBarItem0 = tabBar.items[0] as UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items[1] as UITabBarItem

    tabBarItem0.title = "First"
    tabBarItem1.title = "Second"
```

Can someone explain to me why the first version doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like you realized, `tabBar.items` is an Array of `AnyObject`, which is essentially `id`. You have to downcast it like you did with `as UITabBarItem`.

One better way to do this, which is recommended, is to downcast the entire array before you start accessing. So it would look like this:

```
let tabItems = tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]
tabItems[0].title = "First"
//...
```

Comment: ah - ok. Thanks - I will have a look at the downcasting section again.